# How to change SASS variable properties value if page URL contains some particular text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I want to use the same SASS file for two different websites which are the same in functionality except color. So I want to change the color based on URL. Now my problem is that I am not able to get page URL from SASS file and don't know how to use .contain() inside css.
 **or is this possible to update SASS variable from JS or JQuery ?**

i.e.
URL1 = https://www.myURL.nz.com; 
URL2 = https://www.myURL.au.com;

Now I want to chk if page url contains ".nz" then button color is green else button color is Gray.

*I know bellow syntax is wrong . so pls help with correct syntax and requirement*

```
$URL: need to get the page url;

   @if $URL.contains('.nz') {
      $bg-color: green;
   }@else {
      $bg-color: gray;
   }

.button{
 background : $bg-color 
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply add a class to each of your websites body with a theme name for example ? ex : `<body class="site-1 theme-blue">` / `<body class="site-2 theme-orange">`

Comment: @Jake , No its not possible . Because technically there is only one website with two different url . Thing is Australia ppl want to see the same button in gray color and others wants that in green color . site is already developed so updating HTML classes will be really complicated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `body` class according to your URL? So it would be something like this

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('.nz') > -1 ) {
        $('body').addClass('nz');
    }
});
```

And then in your sass file you can just assign the different colours to the children of `body.nz` like this:

```
$bg-color: gray;

.button{
    background: $bg-color;
}

body.nz {
    $bg-color: green;

    button {
        background : $bg-color;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea , but website is already developed so doing this will break the style.

Comment: @Avinashnayak Still, this should have been studied and integrated into your website way before you reached this point

Comment: but you know client can ask anything at any time. :)

Comment: Sure, I see what you mean @Avinashnayak, although I don't see why this wouldn't work just using the jquery to add the body class and  `body.nz { $bg-color: green !important; }` from my answer above but leaving the rest of your CSS as is.? Can you test it?

Comment: yah !! I got your point ... gonna implement this . Thanks  :)

Comment: @coops , I have tried 
**file 1**  
`$foreground-color2 : red; 
  body.nzSiteBody {   
    $foreground-color2 : blue !important;    
  }`
**File 2**
`import 'file 1';
.bg{
color:$foreground-color2 ;
}`
but above code always taking red color even body containing nzSiteBody . Any clue ???

Answer (score 1):

You could print via javascript the value of `location.href` into a `data-url` attribute of the body element, e.g.

```
<script>
  document.body.dataset.url = location.href;
</script>
```

and your css code would be

```
.button {
  background : gray;
}

[data-url*=".nz"] .button{
  background : green
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJdeLa)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CSS custom properties / variables if your browser supports it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: Most of the browser doen't support VAR()

Comment: 91% global support as of today: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: IE is the murderer  here. client team always start from this browser :(